# Multiple Django functions on class-based view

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for using `Multiple Django functions` in the same Class and display these functions on the same template.

Both functions are in my Django Template, but none work and I don't know why.

**First function :**

This function lets to search a person in my Database based on 3 criteria : `firstname`, `lastname` and `birthcity`. Then I display the query result in my array.

**Second function :**

This function is a simple `Django form`.

This is my first Django Class :

```
class SocieteFormulaire(TemplateView) :

    template_name= "Societe.html"
    model = Societe


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        request = self.request

        if 'recherche' in request.GET:

            query_Lastname_ID = request.GET.get('q1LastnameID')
            query_Firstname_ID = request.GET.get('q1FirstnameID')
            query_BirthCity_ID = request.GET.get('q1BirthCityID')

            sort_params = {}

            set_if_not_none(sort_params, 'Lastname__icontains', query_Lastname_ID)
            set_if_not_none(sort_params, 'Firstname__icontains', query_Firstname_ID)
            set_if_not_none(sort_params, 'BirthCity__icontains', query_BirthCity_ID)

            query_list = Societe_Recherche.Recherche_Filter(Societe, sort_params)

            context = {
                "query_Lastname_ID" : query_Lastname_ID,
                "query_Firstname_ID" : query_Firstname_ID,
                "query_BirthCityID" : query_Birthcity_ID,
                "query_list" : query_list,
            }

            return context


    def get_context_data(self, **kwarg) :

        success = False
        request = self.request

        if request.method == 'POST':

            form = IndividuFormulaire(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

            if form.is_valid() :
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                for element in settings.BDD :
                    post.save(using=element, force_insert=True)

                messages.success(request, 'Le formulaire a été enregistré !')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('IndividuResume', kwargs={'id': post.id}))

            else:
                messages.error(request, "Le formulaire est invalide !")

        else:
            form = IndividuFormulaire()
            form.fields['Utilisateur'].initial = request.user.last_name + " " + request.user.first_name

        context = {
            "form" : form,
            "Individu" : Individu
        }

        return context
```

I named both functions with the same name, because if I don't do that, first function or my form is not displayed on my template.

So my question is : How I can set multiple functions in the same Django Class and in the same Django template ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm trying to improve my code and get object-oriented code. Up to now, I defined my view as a succession of functions. Each function pointed to a Django template. But sometimes I have to get multiple functions i the same template as in my question : search people and create people thanks to Django form.

I'm trying to handle my script because it's ugly and I want to set something better.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Multiple Django functions". What you want is to use multiple views. If you want to use the same template for multiple views, nothing stops you from doing that

Answer (score 2):

You have several misconceptions and misunderstandings here.

You simply can't have two methods with the same name in a Python class. The first one will just be overridden when the class is loaded. The normal solution is to put all the code in one method, or have two with different names and call one from the other.

However, you should also consider that none of this logic belongs in `get_context_data` anyway. That's for preparing context data for the template, not for processing form submissions.

The fundamental problem is that you are picking the wrong class to inherit and then overriding the wrong methods. TemplateView is a very basic class and is certainly not meant to be used like this. The real action of your view is to display and process a form that creates an element; so, you should use CreateView. Then you can get rid of almost all the code in your second method; the view will do all the processing for you, the only thing you will need to do is to define `form_valid` to do your custom save logic.

The search logic could remain in `get_context_data` if you like. But you do need to remember to call the superclass method, and also return context even if `'recherche' in request.GET` is false.

Comment: Ok thank you to your answer. It's the first time I'm using Django class like this and I made lot of mistakes in my script. So I have to replace `class SocieteFormulaire(TemplateView) :` by `class SocieteFormulaire(CreateView) :` and see how this class works ?

Comment: Yes; then delete all of the second `get_context_data` method except for the bit inside `if form.is_valid()` and move that into a separate `form_valid` method.

Comment: Thank you I will try your answer !